# Can not fulfill Nazr (Vow)

Tags: practical-islam

If we vow for any thing and we can not complete this vow for some reason then Allah can take this thing from us towards Allah?

Comment: Consider explaining what mannat is? If it is a vow (nadhr - in Arabic) it depends on the kind of vow so you should specify and **edit** your post.

Comment: Mannat means Vows. See here for more info: https://islamqa.info/en/2587

Answer (score 0):

[Narrated from Ibn Abbas](https://sunnah.com/urn/1264470)

> "Whoever makes a vow and does not state it specifically, the expiation
>   (for such a vow) is the expiation for breaking an oath. Whoever makes
>   a vow and is not able to fulfill it, the expiation for that is the
>   expiation for breaking an oath. Whoever makes a vow and is able to
>   fulfill it, let him do so."

[Sahih al-Bukhari: Narrated Aisha](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/77)

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Whoever vowed to be obedient to Allah, must be
>   obedient to Him; and whoever vowed to be disobedient to Allah, should
>   not be disobedient to Him."

[Sahih al-Bukhari: Narrated Ibn `Umar](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/82/14)

> The Prophet (ﷺ) forbade vowing and said, "In fact, vowing does not
>   prevent anything, but it makes a miser to spend his property."

It's similar to breaking and oath, so whatever is KAFFARAH for oath breaking you have to fulfill.